# Excel IF statement is returning "FALSE"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to write a statement which will read the content of the adjacent cells and select a value depending on the results to punctuate a paragraph. Just like the below sentence is laid out.

Statement 1, Statement 2, Statement 3.

A comma is included if the next statement has content. A full stop is included if the next statement does not have content. Nothing is included if the next and previous statements do not have content. I have used the formula below, but the bit that's supposed to add the full stop is returning FALSE:

```
=IF(A1<>"",IF(C1<>"",", "),IF(A1<>"",IF(C1="",". "),IF(A1="",IF(C1="",""))))
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: you're missing several [value_if_false]. If your if-tests go this way and no [value_if_false] is defined, the formula will return "false" as a result

Comment: Thanks  @Jo.lass but I'm not sure I understand what you mean. It shouldn't be returning a false value anyway, it should find this part to be true?
IF(A1<>"",IF(C1="",". ")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you have overcomplicated your formula. For example you test up to 3 times if A1 is blank

Are you trying to achieve this ?

```
=IF(A1<>"",IF(C1<>"","; ",""),IF(C1="",". ",""))
```

- if A1 is not blank and C1 is not blank = ;
- if A1 is not blank and C1 is blank = nothing
- if A1 is blank and C1 is blank = .
- if A1 is blank and C1 is not blank = nothing

Comment: Thanks @Jo.lass, that's almost right. I'm trying to achieve:

if A1 is not blank and C1 is not blank = ,
if A1 is not blank and C1 is blank = .
if A1 is blank and C1 is blank = nothing

Comment: Based on your formula I've just tried this which works :-)
=IF(A1<>"",IF(C1<>"",", ",". "),IF(C1="","",""))
Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Yes, wasn't sure which one is right ;)  thanks for the feedback

Comment: Curses, foiled again - I took too long drawing out a flowchart of the logic tree

Answer (score 3):

The `IF` statement has this format: `=IF(<Statement>, <Value_If_True>, <Value_If_False>)`

If we break your code down in the same way, we get this:

```
    =IF(<Statement1>, IF_TRUE1(<Statement2>, <Value_If_True2>), IF_FALSE1(<Statement3>, IF_TRUE3(<Statement4>, <Value_If_True4>), IF_FALSE3(<Statement5>, IF_TRUE5(<Statement6>, <Value_If_True6>))))
```

The missing `<Value_If_False>` will return `FALSE` by default.

Now, that might be a bit hard to read, so here's another layout:
[image: Flow Chart of If Statement Logic]

Hopefully you can see all of the duplicate "question" nodes there - and also that the `"."` is impossible to reach, because it requires that `A1<>""` is `FALSE`, and *also* `TRUE`.

Rewriting your code, there is still 1 "missing" terminator:

```
=IF(A1="", IF(C1="", "", FALSE), IF(C1="", ".", ", "))
```

(Or, if you want to be really fancy, use a `CHOOSE` statement:)

```
=CHOOSE(1+(A1="")+2*(C1=""), ", ", FALSE, ".", "")
```

Comment: Damn, that's a great explanation of the original issue - very visual +1

Answer (score 0):

This part of your formula seems redundant as it is already captured in the initial logical arguments:

```
IF(A1<>"",IF(C1="",". "),IF(A1="",IF(C1="","")))
```

I might not understand your objective entirely, but this should do the trick:
I'm assuming statements here are defined by inputs into columns A,B & C and column A has to be filled first.

```
=IF(A1="","",IF(AND(B1="",C1=""),". ",", "))
```

If I'm way off, do share your table/sheet structure with desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, had a go at this just to see:

```
=IF(AND(A1="",C1=""),"",IF(AND(A1<>"",C1<>""),A1&";"&C1,A1&C1&"."))
```

[image]

And if both are not blank, then they should be separated by ";" and finished with "." ...

```
=IF(AND(A1="",C1=""),"",IF(AND(A1<>"",C1<>""),A1&";"&C1&".",A1&C1&"."))
```

See:

[image]